# Не запускается приложение python Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Использую VisualStudio Code

```
c:/Users/рслан/OneDrive/окументы/Workspace/.vscode/Test.py
C:\Python\python.exe: can't open file 'c:\Users\╤А╤Б╨╗╨░╨╜\OneDrive\╨╛╨║╤Г╨╝╨╡╨╜╤В╤Л\Workspace\.vscode\Test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

[image: Сама ошибка]

[image: Что находится в рабочей области]

Comment: Файл не найден из-за кириллицы в пути. Попробуй файл Test.py кинуть в папку, где не будет русских символов в пути.

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, много что сейчас плохо воспринимает кириллицу. Поэтому переместите файл в место, путь к которому будет полностью на латинице.